# how can i add picture in database from php form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

While trying to change ruby version from 2.0.0 to 1.9.3 , its showing this error.

> nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because
>   its executable
>   (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3p484/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/agents/PassengerWatchdog)
>   does not exist. This probably means that your Phusion Passenger
>   installation is broken or incomplete, or that your 'passenger_root'
>   directive is set to the wrong value. Please reinstall Phusion
>   Passenger or fix your 'passenger_root' directive, whichever is
>   applicable. (-1: Unknown error)

How to get rid of this?